# Logcat warning :Consider using Resources.getDrawable(int, Theme) or Context.getDrawable(int)

Tags: android

I found this error when i want to input data but i didn't use any drawables in my code. And I am just using a simple EditText to read the data. I have referred to many other solutions in this forum but it is not work for help.

```
Drawable android:drawable/text_cursor_material has unresolved theme attributes! Consider using Resources.getDrawable(int, Theme) or Context.getDrawable(int).
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:740)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.superGetDrawable(TintResources.java:48)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:44)
    at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.getHotspotX(Editor.java:3772)
    at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.updateDrawable(Editor.java:3399)
```

Edited (The build.gradle)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    // Enabling multidex support.
   // multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
wearApp project(':wear')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'

compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Post your code where you are setting drawable.

Comment: please post your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 3):

Summarizing this [issue](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/issues/1002)

- Use `ContextCompat.getDrawable(Context, int)` instead of `getResources().getDrawable(int)` (which is deprecated).
- Use `0.8.5.7` or higher if available but not `0.8.5.6` of **material-dialogs**.